# How to split a number & add those number split numbers ? Below is the code for splitting the numbers but unable to add up those nodes

Tags: java

Below is the code for splitting the numbers but unable to add up those nodes

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num = 55;
        int j;
        String number = String.valueOf(num);
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
            j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);
            System.out.println(j);

        }
        System.out.println();       
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you're trying to sum the digits. So 14 would give the answer 5 (1+4=5) and 1076 would be 14(=1+0+7+6). So think about how you would do that simplistically by hand.

Comment: You are getting the digits correctly, so now time to think how to get their sum?

Answer (score 1):

Just init the sum variable with zero and sum up the values you get from the Character.digit... call. Prints the values at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 55;
    int sum = 0;
    String number = String.valueOf(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        sum += Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);

}
```

Or in one line with streams:

`System.out.println(String.valueOf(num).chars().map(c -> Character.digit(c, 10)).sum());`